# C# List<> Arrange by another List value

Tags: c#, list

I have a List and I want to sort by another list of sequence.

```
List<string> Source = new List<string>() { "A" ,"B" ,"C" ,"D" ,"E" ,"F" ,"G" };
List<int> Sequence = new List<int>(){ 2, 1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 7 };
```

how can I get the new list so that my results are like

```
List<string> Output = new List<string>(){ "B" ,"A" ,"C" ,"E" ,"D" ,"F" ,"G" };
```

P.S. I can use following code to get the result.But I want to learn another method.

```
    private List<string> ArrangeList(List<string> i_lsData, List<int> i_nSequence)
    {
        List<string> lv_lsTempList = new List<string>();

        foreach(int Temp in i_nSequence)
        {
            lv_lsTempList.Add(i_lsData[Temp]);
        }

        return lv_lsTempList;
    }
```

Comment: Learn to use classes instead of multiple related collections.

Comment: `private List<string> ArrangeList(List<string> i_lsData, List<int> i_nSequence)
        {
            return i_nSequence.Zip(i_lsData, (k, v) => new { k, v }).OrderBy(k => k.k).Select(k => k.v).ToList();
        }`

Comment: What would the result be of the sequence is `{ 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 6, 7 }`?

Comment: It seems that the question can be interpreted in two ways. Does a value of "2" as the first element of `Sequence` mean that the result should contain the second element from the `Source` list first? Or does it mean that the first element of the `Source` should be second in the result list?

Answer (score 5):

You can use LINQ to do the sorting based on the index for you:

```
var list = Source.Select((item, index) => new { Item = item, Index = Sequence[index] })
                 .OrderBy(s => s.Index)
                 .Select(s => s.Item);
```

First I use the `Select` to get the index of the item in `Source` and find the corresponding item in `Sequence`. Then we sort on that and get the original item back.

Answer (score 1):

Or using Zip:

```
var ordered = Source
    .Zip(Sequence, (source, seq) => new { Item = source, Index = seq })
    .OrderBy(s => s.Index)
    .Select(s => s.Item);
```

Zip pairs two enumerables item by item at the same position. The lambda expression can be used to create something (an anonymous method in this case) with the two items at the same position.

In contrast to other solutions, it doesn't call

```
Sequence[index]
```

for each item in the source. But rather it iterates the two collections together. This is better for performance and allows to do the same when no indexed access it possible (say: with two `IEnumerables`).

Answer (score 0):

Here is one LINQ version:

```
var result =
    Source
    .Select((x,i) => new {Item = x, Index = i})
    .OrderBy(v => Sequence.IndexOf(v.Index + 1))
    .Select(v => v.Item)
    .ToList();
```

Comment: Why use `IndexOf` as order?

Comment: That is what I thought of when I tried to solve the problem. It works. But now I see you have a solution that performs better. It wouldn't matter though if the list is small.

Comment: @PatrickHofman, actually, we are solving two different problems.

Comment: Yes, it seems so... :)

Comment: @PatrickHofman, for instance a sequence of `{ 2, 3, 1, 5, 4, 6, 7 }` will produce different results using my answer or your answer.

Comment: Since you sort on the index, not the actual value in it.